# How do active blades work on helicopters?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, noise, blade, aeroelasticity

Can someone throw some light on 'active blades' as used in helicopters? I'm mostly interested in the use of piezoelectric material and actuators.

How are the actuators able to sense the change of aerodynamic forces on the blade?
 What is the subsequent action of the actuators which results in a reduction of noise level of the rotor?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how the rotor blades are chamging their angle of attack?

Comment: The idea is to have [flaps on the trailing edge, moved by piezoelectric actuators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgXUW.png) or benders within the blade, which displacement is mechanically amplified. The flaps change the airfoil to cancel blade vibrations (e.g. by twisting the blade). A variation is to deform the whole width of the blade. The principle of a piezoelectric material is it changes its length when an electric field is applied on its faces (and vice-versa). This [article seems interesting](https://ilot.edu.pl/eng_prace_ilot/public/PDF/list_of_transactions/184_2006/Miller_Narkiewicz.pdf).

Comment: This should answer your question:

https://www.icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2008/PAPERS/842.PDF